# Travis gives me Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, redis, travis-ci

I'm trying to test a node.js [module](https://github.com/luiselizondo/config-persistence) using Travis, but all I get is "Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED".

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? The latest build is at: https://travis-ci.org/luiselizondo/config-persistence/builds/65187913

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a look at your problem and it seems the problem is due to the format of your `.travis.yml` file.

I forked your project and removed the leading spaces in front of the `language` and `node_js` fields. I have created a pull request [here](https://github.com/luiselizondo/config-persistence/pull/2) that shows the changes I made.

You can see the result of my build [here](https://travis-ci.org/cotsog/config-persistence/builds/65403996).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Dominic. Just to learn but how did you know that it was a format problem?

Comment: No Problem Luis. I was adding a `netstat` statement to check the state of the redis server port and it was not executing. Plus in Github, you have this nice editor view that shows the spaces and I saw that the 2 first fields did not have the same indentation as the rest of the file.

Comment: Ups, dump mistake. Thanks.